# Unable to display image in template (Django 3.0)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**Unable to display profile_pic image in template** 
I know i m doing something very terrible.
**model.py**

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='basic_app/profile_pics',blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

**index.html**

```
{% block body_block %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Django Level Five</h1>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <h2>Welcome {{ user.username }}!</h2>
            <div>
                <img src="{{ user.profile_pic.url }}" alt="user-image">
            </div>

        {% else %}
            <h2>Welcome to the site!</h2>
            {% for b in users %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
   #commented: userpro = UserProfileInfo()
   #commented: var={'userz': userpro}
   #commented: return render(request, 'basic_app/index.html',context=var)

   return render(request, 'basic_app/index.html')
```

#### User authentication is fine and name is getting displayed in template but not the image. I have tried lot of things but image didn't show. Div and Alt-name getting displayed but not the profile_pic.

Comment: You are not accessing your Model, you are using Django Authentication, so the fields you could access there, are this ones: [Django User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user object does not have a profile_pic field.

try using:

user.userprofileinfo.profile_pic.url

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. @Ethan Can you explain little bit of logic ? What is "userprofileinfo" ? My model name isn't that. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Pretty much python is a scripting language so files are read top to bottom. What that means is you can only reference objects that are physically above your model in the code as opposed to a language like Java (There are ways around this but lets keep things simple). But obviously you still need to reference things below your code. So Django behind the scenes gives you the relation from User to UserProfileInfo with the lower case convention. Hope that helps

Comment: Yeah, it helped. Simple and precise. Thank you so much @Ethan